# Laravel: Integrate Braintree with Cashier

Tags: php, laravel, braintree, laravel-cashier

Just curious,

Does someone has successfully integrated Braintree using [`laravel/cashier-braintree`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing) ?

I'm stuck at the beginning with:
`$user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')->create($creditCardToken);`

Following the documentation, I guess to need something like that:

    `$data = [
        'firstName' => $request->first_name,
        'lastName' => $request->last_name,
    ];
    $creditCardToken = Auth::id(); 
    $planId = [Plan Id defined in Braintree]
    $user->newSubscription('main', $planId)->create($creditCardToken, $data);`

In the [offical documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create/php#credit_card.number) I dont have to specify any credit card info, it's deprecated.

`"Unable to create Braintree customer: Unknown payment_method_nonce.\n
    Expiration date is required.\n
    Credit card number is required.\n
    Credit card must include number, payment_method_nonce, or venmo_sdk_payment_method_code."`

Whoops! So let's add this anyway: 

    `$data = [
        'firstName' => $request->first_name,
        'lastName' => $request->last_name,
        'creditCard' => [
            'number' => $request->number,
            'expirationMonth' => $request->month,
            'expirationYear' => $request->year,
            'cvv' => $request->cvv,
            'billingAddress' => [
                'firstName' => 'Jen',
                'lastName' => 'Smith',
                'company' => 'Braintree',
                'streetAddress' => '123 Address',
                'locality' => 'City',
                'region' => 'State',
                'postalCode' => '12345',
            ],
        ],
    ];`

And now, all I get is :
`"Unable to create Braintree customer: Unknown payment_method_nonce."`

There is some usefull informations in the official [Braintree_Customer::create()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create/php). And, in fact, you can easily implement Braintree without *cachier* like in [braintree_php_guide](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php_guide/blob/master/3_recurring_billing/subscription.php).

So what ? Do I have to drop *Cachier* ?

Comment: My bad, it's tagged [unstable](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-braintree)

Answer (score 1):

Cashier with braintree is already working (for me at least). The start was a little confusing for me as well.

The idea behind that is, that the user sends his critical credit card data directly to braintree and not to you. So you need a form, that sends its data to Braintree (via javascript). After that you receive a token back (the `payment_method_nonce`). You have to use this token afterwards to bill the user.

So I implemented it the following way in Laravel 5.2. It is a little bit more complicated on the implementation, as I wanted to use bootstrap format. You can accomplish this easier (with less flexibility) by using the older [javascript v2 SDK](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2).

My implementation:

**/app/Http/routes.php**

```
Route::get      ('upgrade', 'AccountController@getUpgrade')->name('account.upgrade');
Route::post     ('upgrade', 'AccountController@postUpgrade');
```

**/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Braintree_Configuration::environment(env('BRAINTREE_ENV'));
        \Braintree_Configuration::merchantId(env('BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID'));
        \Braintree_Configuration::publicKey(env('BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY'));
        \Braintree_Configuration::privateKey(env('BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY'));

        \Laravel\Cashier\Cashier::useCurrency('eur', '€');

        // ....
    }
    // ...
}
```

**/app/Http/Controllers/AccountController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    // ..

    public function getUpgrade()
    {
        return view('account.upgrade');
    }

    public function postUpgrade(Request $request)
    {
        $plan = 'myservice-yearly';

        $nonce = $request->input('payment-method-nonce');

        // optional user data
        $user = $request->user();
        $user_data = [
            'id' =>     'myservice_'.$user->id,
            'email' =>  $user->email,
        ];

        // optional subscription data
        $subscription_data = [];

        $user->newSubscription('main', $plan)
            ->create($nonce, $user_data, $subscription_data);

        return 'thank-you';
    }
}
```

**/resources/views/account/upgrade.blade.php**

```
<h1>Upgrade</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="paypal_button"><i class="fa fa-paypal"></i> Mit PayPal zahlen</button>
<hr>
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'account.upgrade', 'class'=>'panel-body', 'id'=> 'paymentform']) !!}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <label class="control-label">credit card number</label>
            <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
            <div class="form-control" id="card-number"></div>
            <span class="helper-text"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-12">expiration date</label>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
                    <div class="form-control" id="expiration-month"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
                    <div class="form-control" id="expiration-year"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <label class="control-label">security code (CCV)</label>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
            <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
            <div class="form-control" id="cvv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Pay with <span id="card-type">credit card</span></button>

    <input type="hidden" name="payment-method-nonce" value="">
{!! Form::close() !!}

<!-- Load the Client component. -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.4.0/js/client.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load additional components if desired. -->
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.4.0/js/hosted-fields.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.4.0/js/paypal.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        braintree.client.create({
            authorization: '{{ Braintree\ClientToken::generate() }}'
        }, function (err, clientInstance) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }

            braintree.paypal.create({
                client: clientInstance
            }, function (err, paypalInstance) {
                $('#paypal_button').click(function () {
                    // Tokenize here!
                    paypalInstance.tokenize({
                        flow: 'vault', // Required
                        billingAgreementDescription: 'MyService Premium'
                    }, function (err, payload) {
                        console.log(payload);
                        $('input[name="payment-method-nonce"]').val(payload.nonce);
                        $('#paymentform').submit();
                    });
                });
            });

            braintree.hostedFields.create({
                client: clientInstance,
                styles: {
                    'input': {
                        'font-size': '14px',
                        'font-family': 'helvetica, tahoma, calibri, sans-serif',
                        'color': '#3a3a3a'
                    },
                    ':focus': {
                        'color': 'black'
                    }
                },
                fields: {
                    number: {
                        selector: '#card-number',
                        placeholder: '4111 1111 1111 1111'
                    },
                    cvv: {
                        selector: '#cvv',
                        placeholder: '123'
                    },
                    expirationMonth: {
                        selector: '#expiration-month',
                        placeholder: 'MM'
                    },
                    expirationYear: {
                        selector: '#expiration-year',
                        placeholder: 'JJ'
                    }
                }
            }, function (err, hostedFieldsInstance) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }

                hostedFieldsInstance.on('validityChange', function (event) {
                    var field = event.fields[event.emittedBy];

                    if (field.isValid) {
                        if (event.emittedBy === 'expirationMonth' || event.emittedBy === 'expirationYear') {
                            if (!event.fields.expirationMonth.isValid || !event.fields.expirationYear.isValid) {
                                return;
                            }
                        } else if (event.emittedBy === 'number') {
                            $('#card-number').next('span').text('');
                        }

                        // Apply styling for a valid field
                        $(field.container).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
                    } else if (field.isPotentiallyValid) {
                        // Remove styling  from potentially valid fields
                        $(field.container).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-warning');
                        $(field.container).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-success');
                        if (event.emittedBy === 'number') {
                            $('#card-number').next('span').text('');
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Add styling to invalid fields
                        $(field.container).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-warning');
                        // Add helper text for an invalid card number
                        if (event.emittedBy === 'number') {
                            $('#card-number').next('span').text('Looks like this card number has an error.');
                        }
                    }
                });

                hostedFieldsInstance.on('cardTypeChange', function (event) {
                    // Handle a field's change, such as a change in validity or credit card type
                    if (event.cards.length === 1) {
                        $('#card-type').text(event.cards[0].niceType);
                    } else {
                        $('#card-type').text('Card');
                    }
                });

                $('#paymentform').submit(function (event) {
                    var value = $('input[name="payment-method-nonce"]').val();
                    console.log(event);
                    console.log('nonce=' + value);

                    if (value == '') {
                        //console.log('preventing');
                        event.preventDefault();
                        hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (err, payload) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error(err);
                                return;
                            }

                            // This is where you would submit payload.nonce to your server
                            $('input[name="payment-method-nonce"]').val(payload.nonce);
                            $('#paymentform').submit();
                        });
                    } /*else {
                        console.log('should submit');
                    }*/
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

See also:

- [Set Up Your Client (JS v3 SDK)](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3)
- [Set Up Your Client (JS v2 SDK)](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2)